# On refresh or on sorting, a new grid open inside existing gridview

Tags: layout

The grid is working properly but whenever I click on the column label to sort or reset the filter it opens a new grid inside the existing grid.

[image: Magento Grid View]

**config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>

     <modules>
       <Shopper_Cart>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
       </Shopper_Cart>
     </modules>

     <frontend>
        <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
            <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                <module>Shopper_Cart</module>
                <frontName>test</frontName>
             </args>
          </routeurfrontend>
        </routers>
      <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <shopper_cart>
                <class>shopper_cart/observer</class>
                <method>newCustomer</method>
                </shopper_cart>
            </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
       </events>
       <layout>
          <updates>
             <cart>
               <file>front.xml</file>
             </cart>
          </updates>
       </layout>
     </frontend>

     <global>
         <models>
            <shopper_cart>
                    <class>Shopper_Cart_Model</class>
                    <resourceModel>shopper_cart_resource</resourceModel>
                </shopper_cart>
                <shopper_cart_resource>
                    <class>Shopper_Cart_Model_Resource</class>
                    <entities>
                        <vendor>
                            <table>shopper_cart_vendor</table>
                        </vendor>
                        <order>
                            <table>shopper_cart_order</table>
                        </order>                    
                    </entities>
             </shopper_cart_resource>
         </models>

        <!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->
       <resources>
           <shopper_cart_setup>
               <setup>
                   <module>Shopper_Cart</module>
               </setup>
               <connection>
                   <use>core_setup</use>
               </connection>
           </shopper_cart_setup>
        </resources>

         <blocks>
          <cart>
            <class>Shopper_Cart_Block</class>
          </cart>
       </blocks>

        <helpers>
             <cart>
               <class>Shopper_Cart_Helper</class>
              </cart>
         </helpers>
     </global>
       <admin>
         <routers>
             <cart>
                <use>admin</use> 
                <args>
                   <module>Shopper_Cart</module>
                    <frontName>admintest</frontName>
                </args>
             </cart>
          </routers>
     </admin>
     <adminhtml>
         <layout>
           <updates>
               <cart>
                    <file>backend.xml</file>
                </cart>
            </updates>
        </layout>
         <menu>
          <test translate="title" module="adminhtml">
             <title>Vendors Management</title>
             <sort_order>100</sort_order>
             <children>
                 <item1>
                       <title>Manage Vendors</title>
                       <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
                  </item1>
                   <item2>
                       <title>Manage Orders</title>
                       <action>admintest/adminhtml_index/order</action>
                  </item2>
                   <item3>
                       <title>Manage Transaction</title>
                       <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
                  </item3>
                   <item4>
                       <title>Manage Summary</title>
                       <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
                  </item4>
              </children>
           </test>
        </menu>
     </adminhtml> 
     </config>
```

**order.php**

```
<?php

class Shopper_Cart_Block_Adminhtml_Plugins_Order extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
     //where is the controller
     $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_plugins_order';  //the path to your grid block. 
     $this->_blockGroup = 'cart'; //blockGroup is module name # the first part of the grouped class name, i.e. (some_module)/whatever
     $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('cart')->__('Order Manager'); # sets the name in the header
     $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('cart')->__('Add an Order'); # sets the text for the add button
     //value of the add button
    parent::__construct(); # for grid containers, parent constructor must be called last - not good design
    }
    /**
     * Header CSS class
     *
     * Used to set the icon next to the header text, not at all needed but a
     * nice touch. Look at all the headers to see the available icons, or make
     * your own by omitting this and making a CSS rule for .head-adminhtml-thing
     *
     * @return string The CSS class
     */
    public function getHeaderCssClass()
    {
        return 'icon-head head-cms-page';
    }
}
```

**Grid.php**

```
<?php

class Shopper_Cart_Block_Adminhtml_Plugins_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid

    {
      public function __construct()
    {
       $this->_objectId = 'id';
        //vwe assign the same blockGroup as the Grid Container
        $this->_blockGroup = 'cart';
        //and the same controller
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_plugins_order';  //the path to your grid block. 
        //define the label for the save and delete button

        parent::__construct();
         // Set some defaults for our grid
        $this->setId('o_id'); 
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('shopper_cart/order')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
       return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the solution.. just by removing the `$this->setUseAjax(true);` from function _construct().

```
class Shopper_Cart_Block_Adminhtml_Plugins_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid

    {
      public function __construct()
    {
       $this->_objectId = 'id';
        //vwe assign the same blockGroup as the Grid Container
        $this->_blockGroup = 'cart';
        //and the same controller
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_plugins_order';  //the path to your grid block. 
        //define the label for the save and delete button

        parent::__construct();
         // Set some defaults for our grid

        $this->setId('o_id'); 
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        **//$this->setUseAjax(true);**
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('shopper_cart/order')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
       return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a  mistake in `gridAction()`
Try below code.

```
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cart/adminhtml_plugins_order‌​_grid')->toHtml());
}
```

Comment: public function gridAction()

  { $this->_title($this->__('Order Manager'))->_title($this->__('Order Manager'));
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu;
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cart/adminhtml_plugins_order_grid'));
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('cart')->__('Add Comment'); 
    $this->renderLayout();
    }

Comment: i have update the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Important**

Name `cart` for block declaration is used in core. So you need to change this to something else.
**You must always try to avoid this at all the time.**

You need to add `gridAction()` in your controller.

Add this function in your controller that is related to your grid:

```
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
                    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cart/adminhtml_plugins_order‌_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}
```

This will be called when you sort.

**Assumption**

You need to make sure your controller block is called appropriately in `adminhtml_plugins_order‌.php` file.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'cart';
        $this->_controller = 'plugins_order‌'; //this is important
        $this->_headerText = 'Your Header';
        ................

        parent::__construct();
        .........
    }


public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/<controller_name>/grid', array('_current' => true));
}
```

Comment: it's still giving the same result..

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: call to member function toHtml() on a non-object

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eQiCr.png

Comment: I hope `cart` is your block declaration in config and `adminhtml_plugins_order‌_grid` is block path for `grid.php`

Comment: public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        //vwe assign the same blockGroup as the Grid Container
        $this->_blockGroup = 'cart';
        //and the same controller
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_plugins_order';  //the path to your grid block. 
        //define the label for the save and delete button

Comment: You should call `parent::__construct()` after `$this->_controller` in construct function.

Comment: `public function __construct()
    {
       $this->_blockGroup = 'cart';
        //and the same controller
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_plugins_order';  //the path to your grid block. 
        //define the label for the save and delete button

        parent::__construct();`

Comment: Correct, and still error?

Comment: yes.. the same error..

Comment: You need to add your config and block codes, to see what's going on. or else just check with this link: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Comment: plez update in your question.

Comment: My initial guess is, your `cart` block declaration in config.xml is getting confused with core declaration. So please change to something else.